# Frobenius norm of Fourier matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

The Fourier matrix is given by

[image]

where $\omega = e^{-2\pi i/N}$. Is there any clever way to calculate Frobenius norm of Fourier matrix?

I tried solving it with brute force and got some ugly calculations

Comment: Do you know what’s the formula to compute the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @lcv, yes I do. You can google it if you want to know

Comment: Thank you . So you only need to compute the sum of the absolute values squared of all the entries. Note that each entry has modulus one. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @lcv, thanks, what I didnt see is that each entry squared has modulus one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward computation using any reasonable definition of the Frobenius norm.  For instance, we have
$$
\|W\| = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(W^*W)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(I)} = \sqrt{N}
$$
where $W^*W = I$ since $W$ is a unitary matrix.